# Phantomjs unable to get refreshed content from HTML website by aspx

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I wanted to get the real time update of an value displayed on a website
Website: http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/market/bmpfutures.aspx
Target html element id: font26 bold cls ff-arial

and i have been using phantomjs code as the following

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/market/bmpfutures.aspx', function(status) {
  var last_value = -1

  setInterval(function() {
    var value = page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.getElementsByClassName('font26 bold cls ff-arial')[0].innerText
    })

    if (value != last_value) {
      console.log("Value as been updated to " + value)
      last_value = value
    }
  }, 1000)
//  phantom.exit()
})
```

with the screenshot here:
[image]

The problem is when the code is first run, it is able to get the value, but after that, the value is cached and not be able to update.

even tried with

```
var needle = require('needle');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
needle.get('http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/market/bmpfutures.aspx', 
function(error, response) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    var value = $('#font26 bold cls ff-arial').html()
    console.log(value)
  }

});
```

Comment: Why do you think it's cached? It should work fine. Consider changing selector to `document.querySelector('.tp-index-td2-2 .last').innerText` for the sake of testing — then the interval will detect change every time data is scrolled.

Comment: @Vaviloff you can see the value is not updated, at the time u try, the market may be closed, so the value stayed the same. I have updated my question with a screenshot that may help

Comment: may be page is not getting refresh. You can again try to `open` same page again and try if it works.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawalnope, the page is refreshing on its own(without refreshing the website), it is a real-time update webpage

Comment: How often does the value refresh?

Comment: @Vaviloff per second

Comment: For some reason it's not refreshing at all. Latest Chrome, adblockers off, doesn't change. Once in a while the page hits API endpoint at http://www.aastocks.com/en/resources/datafeed/getstockindex.ashx?type=5 Can that be of use?

Comment: @Vaviloff I hv also tried adding random parameter at the url, it doesn’t work

Comment: I mean it's not refreshing in Chrome either. Are you sure it must work in real time, do you see it in your normal browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194355/discussion-between-edison-lo-and-vaviloff).

Comment: So, were you able to set up the monitoring, Edison?

Comment: @Vaviloff Yes i am able to set this up. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the needed value on the target page won't update in real time, so we will have to move interval out of the `page.open` callback to the main scope and just refresh the page as often as necessary:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var last_value = -1;

setInterval(function() {

    page.open('http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/market/bmpfutures.aspx', function(status) {

        var value = page.evaluate(function() {
          return document.getElementsByClassName('font26 bold cls ff-arial')[0].innerText
        })

        if (value != last_value) {
            console.log("Value as been updated to " + value)
            last_value = value;
        }
    });

}, 3000)
```

Obviously it's better not to hit the target site too often, also you should add a valid user agent, set a realistic resolution and rotate IPs.

**P.S.**

Just looked at the source of the page and it turned out you don't even need PhantomJS, as `<div class="font26 bold cls ff-arial">26,696</div>` is right there in the HTML. You can get it with any scripted server-side language.

**UPDATE on node migration**

You've almost done it right! The nuance was in the way to compose the selector. Since all those classes belong to one element you need to put them down like this:

```
const needle = require('needle');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

setInterval(function(){
    needle.get('http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/market/bmpfutures.aspx', 
    function(error, response) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
        var value = $('.font26.bold.cls.ff-arial').html().trim()
        console.log(value)
      }
    })
}, 1000)
```

Comment: it seems working fine, but i got one error here
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.getResponseHeader("X-AdSource").includes("PSA")')

not sure if it will affect the performance. I am looking for highly stable method because i will call to refresh every second for around 14 hours in a day.

Any suggestion on other scripted server-side language? I have tried php but it looks unstable to get the result every second. Phantomjs is more stable which i am currently using, i am open to other more stable / efficient solution!

Comment: That error has something to do with ads on the page, it's irrelevant. I strongly believe that any other solution would be more performant in this case because PhantomJS is a whole (albeit headless) browser and it will load all sorts of scripts, ads, images while opening the page thus hurting performance. Also not sure how long will it be able to run for every second.

Comment: I'd suggest using node.js with some lightweight module for getting URLs, like [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle) and then parse HTML with [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) and then maybe daemonize all that with [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Comment: i have tried wt u suggest but failed, u can see my edit post. If you can update ur answer with a working piece of code of ur suggestion, it would be great and i will reward this bounty to u

Comment: Usually I'd suggest opening a new question for this but you've done like 96% of the new solution so I corrcted just a bit of code in the update to the answer.